# What happens when i start an ant build and keep coding, are my changes (after running ant build) neglect or not?

Tags: java, build, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using Intellij IDEA, working on a Hybris project. We use ant for build, but the build takes too long (about 15 min), so when i start the build, I must stop coding, so i lose a lot of time.
My question is, can I keep coding while the build is running? Or will my uncomplete extra code make the build fail?
Thank you

Comment: Just dont save the new code youve typed until the build is complete

Comment: No idea if code changes during the build will make any difference but it is easily testable on hand ;) Still if this is a productive env(i mean professional work/job) then first of all your organization should invest some money into hardware... Still remember the days I've been waiting 20 mins on GWT project to build just cuz my boss did not want to spend money on hardware ;)

Comment: Also, since you have all the time in the world try finding some help on speeding the process up and see if you can improve it in any way.

Comment: Why not write new code in a different area to the build area then copy it in once the build is finished?

Comment: @jdpjamesp because u need autocomplete when u use many services and populators..

Comment: Why build so often? I use hybris and IntelliJ for several projects and I don't have this issue. Builds usually take around 1 to 2 minutes. And you're good with just running "ant" instead of "ant clean all" most of the times. Maybe you're also including the time of the server startup?

Comment: @leaber acctually it's a huge project, e-commerce base for 24 webSite we some shared addons, and so much gulp to do in each build, that's why it takes so much time.

Answer (score 2):

> can I keep coding while the build is running?

No, you should not change the code while the build is going on. Yes, you can keep changes unsaved :)

> will my uncomplete extra code make the build fail?

Yes, it might.

> I lose a lot of time.

Use code hot-swapping tools, like [Jrebel](https://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/)(Licenced), [DCEVM](http://dcevm.github.io/)(opensource).

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not possible to edit while building. You might end up with an inconsistent build. If you want to speed up development, try to set up something like jRebel.

Answer (score -1):

you can just separate editing from building process by build on another computer device or try CI while you are using any CVS like GitLab, GitHub.